# Как научить программу описывать графики?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Хочу научить программу находить закономерности и описывать их в виде текста. Изначально я имею данные следующего вида:

```
{
  "2018-02": 4665,
  "2018-03": 4658.5,
  "2018-04": 4813,
  "2018-05": 4863,
  "2018-06": 4813,
  "2018-07": 5366,
  "2018-08": 4813,
  "2018-09": 4863,
  "2018-10": 4863,
  "2018-11": 4767,
  "2018-12": 5414.5,
  "2019-01": 5362.5
}
```

Слева - год и месяц, справа - минимальная цена на товар, зафиксированная в каждом конкретном месяце. Из этих данных я строю график изменения цен на год вперёд:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что мне нужно, так это научить программу описывать этот график. Например, в этом случае, я бы хотел получить текст следующего содержания:

> Минимальные цены на товар зафиксированы в феврале и марте 2018 года и не превышают отметки в 4600 рублей. В среднем цена на товар составляет 4800 рублей в апреле, мае и июне. Затем в июле происходит резкий скачок до 5366 рублей, однако затем цена снова опускается до уровня 4800 рублей и сохраняет эту планку в августе, сентябре, октябре и ноябре. После чего демонстрирует резкий рост декабре до 5415 рублей и медленный спад до 5363 рублей в январе следующего года

Код за меня писать я ни в коем случае не прошу. Мне интересно решить эту задачу самостоятельно. Прошу лишь объяснить и рассказать о возможных способах решения моей задачи. В частности, интересуют способы обработки представленного выше массива данных с ценами не просто по порядку, мол, "в феврале цена была 4665, в марте подросла до 4658, а в апреле и вовсе достигла 4800". Как определять как резкие скачки цен, так и стабильность и неизменность ценника в определённых периодах. Как обработать информацию так, чтобы программа понимала, что когда-то раннее цена была 4800, потом произошёл скачок/рост/небольшой подъём, а затем цена снова опустилась до ранее уже определённых стабильных 4800.

Answer (score 1):

Создать набор паттернов, например

- резкий скачок
- резкое падение
- период стабильности
- минимальное
- максимальное
- постепенное увеличение
- постепенное уменьшение
- ...

И для каждого паттерна свой алгоритм обнаружения, критерии нахождения.
Соответсвенно проходимся по всем имеющимся паттернам по данному графику и ищем вхождения.

Это базовая идея, дальше можно развивать.

Можно вручную проанализировать определённое количество графиков, и на основе анализа можно будет понять как работать алгоритму, где общие части и как это закодировать.